# Printing data from an android application using a bluetooth printer

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have developed an application in which there is an activity in which i need to fill in some details and then print that data using bluetooth by a bluetooth printer.

I have implemented the code which turns on the bluetooth of the device,scans the bluetooth devices in the range.

Can anyone guide me how to proceed further?

I have read that for printing `google cloud print` is used.Can anyone guide me that is google cloud print useful for me?

Comment: have you seen this? https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/?hl=de

Comment: or better this: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android?hl=de

Comment: @AditiSharma have you got solution?